# How do you iterate within an Azure Logic App Response component

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure MS SQL Server component that is returning multiple rows and feeding into a Response component.

The Body of the Response component looks like this:

```
{
"MyID":"@{body('Get_rows')['value'][1]['Id']}"
}
```

I can make the number in the bracket 0 and get the first result. I can make it 1 and get the second result. But what I am trying to find is the syntax to loop through all the results that are passed so that it would effectively provide the following (assuming there were 2 results total:

```
{
"MyID":"@{body('Get_rows')['value'][0]['Id']}"
}
{
"MyID":"@{body('Get_rows')['value'][1]['Id']}"
}
```

Thanks in advance for advice on where to find the correct syntax or for examples of correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while but figured out that I needed to do two things:

1. I had to run a for each after the Get Rows and within that I created a Data Operations - Compose component. Within that I was able to create a single JSON object with all the parameters.
2. From there I used @outputs command as shown below in the Body of the Response and it inserted the array brackets and the commas to delimit the Compose entries automagically.

Here is what the code in the Body of the Response looks like:

```
@outputs('Compose')
```

Note that 'Compose' is the default name given to the first Compose component  you place in the application.